# Pass some parameters from the action to a form view

Tags: xml, view, odoo

To specify, I am on the base.view_partner_form. I have inserted a new page there like this:

```xml
<record id="view_partner_get_Emails" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.property.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <page name="internal_notes" position="before">
            <page string="Emails">
                <field name="mail_message_lines" mode="tree" style="overflow:hidden;">
                    <tree string="Emails">
                        <field name="date" />
                        <field name="subject" />
                        <field name="partner_ids" />
                        <field name="cc" />
                        <field name="email_from" />
                        <field name="body" style="height: 40px; overflow:hidden;" />
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </page>
        </page>
    </field>
</record>
```

This page holds some emails that I have inserted on the mail.message table (many2many relationship between mail.message and res.partner)

On the click of any email, the mail.view_message_form opens up that has be modified by me as well (setting some fields read only).

My question is the following: When I click an email in a res.partner's form I want the ID of that partner to be passed along to the new form in the context of it. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess it right: you want to auto fill partner_ids? Try to set the current opened partner in context, like:

```xml
<field name="mail_message_lines" mode="tree" style="overflow:hidden;" context={'default_partner_ids':[active_id]}>...</field>
```

Comment: I didn't exactly want to do that, I wanted only to pass the partner_id in my new form so that I could do some searches. Your answer helped me resolve my issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you try this with new record which is not save currently ? because active_id only and only available after save any records.

Answer (score 1):

Your purpose will be resolved by defining inline form view there.

```
<page string="Emails">
    <field name="mail_message_lines" mode="tree" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <tree string="Emails">
            <field name="date" />
            <field name="subject" />
            <field name="partner_ids" />
            <field name="cc" />
            <field name="email_from" />
            <field name="body" style="height: 40px; overflow:hidden;" />          
        </tree>
        <form string="Emails">
            <field name="date" readonly="1" />
            <field name="subject" readonly="1" />
            <field name="partner_ids" readonly="1" />
            <field name="cc" />
            <field name="email_from" />
            <field name="body" style="height: 40px; overflow:hidden;" />
        </form>
   </field>
</page>
```

No need to pass parameter to set fields **readonly / invisible**, however you can do this directly in inline view.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662048/hide-lines-on-tree-view-openerp-7/37670777#37670777) to see one more answer.